# Swift - Search Bar Initial Load

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am attempting to have a search functionality within my app. The search would basically search for user input in the Parse class in the backend.

So far the code below works very well for my case except that as soon as the view loads (prior to starting typing anything) it loads all the usernames in the backend in the table rows. As the user types letters, it filters. I want to have all the same functionality, except for showing all users in table rows as soon as view loads. How can this be achieved?

```
class FriendByUsernameTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

    var friendObject = FriendClass()

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

        var searchActive : Bool = false
    var data:[PFObject]!
    var filtered:[PFObject]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.searchBar.delegate = self
        search()
    }

    func search(searchText: String? = nil){

        let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        if(searchText != nil){
            query.whereKey("appUsername", containsString: searchText)
        }
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results, error) -> Void in
            self.data = results as? [PFObject]!
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(self.data != nil){
            return self.data.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell


        let obj = self.data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = obj["appUsername"] as? String


        return cell
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true;
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        search(searchText)
    }


}
```

The code is based on this tutorial: http://shrikar.com/parse-search-in-ios-8-with-swift/

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
if searchText!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceCharacterSet()) != "" {
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock()
}
```

in your search function along with the block of course.

This way you won't query if you click on the search bar or if you tap a bunch of spaces.

Also, if you don't want users to be displayed upon load, don't call `search()` in your `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: That's not going to solve the issue at hand. The issue is that the view loads with results displaying already where as I want it to only show results when search field received a username

Comment: @ksa_coder See my edit. By calling `search()` in `viewDidLoad()` you are running the query and loading your array with objects, without comparing username to searchText, and hence your tableView will display all users in your users class.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late response. Tried your code above and it lead to an error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: The code I posted was so that you don't get results without typing a non white space character. I misunderstood, and I am force unwrapping searchText so you have to make sure to check if it is not nil, still, if you don't want results upon view load, do not query in viewDidLoad(). Try your query in searchBarTextDidBeginEditing()